# Capistrano first deploy doens't work due to missing development.log file

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano

I want to deploy a website the first time using Rails 3.2.1 with capistrano 2.8.0.

When it comes to "rake db:migrate" the process is aborted:

```
* executing `deploy:migrate'
* executing "cd /home/user/public_html/website.com/releases/20120323114534 && bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production  db:migrate"
servers: ["23.11.63.203"]
[23.11.63.203] executing command
** [out :: 23.11.63.203] rake aborted!
** [out :: 23.11.63.203] No such file or directory - /home/user/public_html/website.com/releases/20120323114534/log/production.log
```

I'm deploying via github, here is relevant part of my deploy.rb:

```
require 'bundler/capistrano'
require 'whenever/capistrano'
set :rails_env, 'production'
set :application, "website.com"
set :domain, "website.com"
set :user, "user"
set :sudo_use, false
set :repository, "git@github.com:User/website.com.git"
set :local_repository,  '~/rails_projects/website.com/.git'
set :deploy_to, "/home/user/public_html/#{application}"
set :scm, :git
set :branch, "master"
default_run_options[:pty] = true
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true

server "23.11.63.203", :app, :web, :db, :primary => true

after "deploy", "deploy:bundle_gems"
after "deploy:bundle_gems", "deploy:restart"
after "deploy:update_code", "deploy:migrate"

namespace :deploy do

  task :bundle_gems do
     run "cd #{deploy_to}/current && bundle install vendor/gems"
  end

  ...(there are some more tasks, but I think they cannot be relevant)

end
```

I tried the following in my deploy.rb, but it was not working, so maybe it's the wrong way to resolve this:

```
after "deploy", "deploy:create_production_log"
namespace :deploy do

  desc "Creates the production log if it does not exist"
  task :create_production_log do
    unless File.exist?(File.join(shared_path, 'log', 'production.log'))
      puts "\n\n=== Creating Production Log! ===\n\n"
      run "touch #{File.join(shared_path, 'log', 'production.log')}"
    end
  end

end
```

How can I do my first deploy in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you perform `cap deploy:setup` and does `cap deploy:check` tells you everything's ok ?

Otherwise, I'd say it's because the `log` dir doesn't exist, probably because you don't have it under version control

Comment: Thanks, that got me to the right track. After cap deploy:setup and cap:deploy:check (which was ok) now the error was a little different (Permission denied - /home/user/public_html/website.com/releases/20120323132001/log/production.log). This was easy to fix with chown...